# TTL in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the elasticsearch python client to create and store data to a aws elasticsearch instance.

```
def create_index():
    """
        create mapping of data
    """
    mappings = '''
    {
        "tweet":{
            "_ttl":{
                "enabled": true,
                "default": "2m"
            },
            "properties": {
                "text":{
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "location":{
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    '''
    # Ignore if index already exists
    es.indices.create(index='tweetmap', ignore=400, body=mappings)
```

As defined above, now I am expecting the records to be deleted automatically after 2 minutes, however they are persisting.

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: You mean 2 minutes, not 2 seconds. Is this cluster using Shield?

Comment: Yes I mean 2 minutes. I am very new to elasticsearch so do not fully understand shield. How can I check that ?

Comment: @AndreiStefan https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-elasticsearch-service/ says AWS ES currently does not support Shield plugin so I guess answer to your query should be a no ?

Comment: How do you add the documents to ES (provide a full command for adding a document that you expect to be deleted)? Can you give an example of a document that was not deleted and it should have? (use `GET /YOUR_INDEX_NAME/tweet/NOT_DELETED_DOCUMENT_ID?fields=_ttl`

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with the way I had defined mappings, corrected it as shown below:

```
mappings = '''
    {
        "mappings":{
            "tweet":{
                "_ttl":{
                    "enabled": true,
                    "default": "1d"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "text":{
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location":{
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    '''
```